# Show that any two completions of a metric space X are isometric by way of an isometry that is the identity mapping on X.

Tags: real-analysis

This is quite obvious by definition of completion of metric space, but how to write it down rigorously?

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space. Then the completion of the metric space, $(\tilde{X},\tilde{\rho})$, where $X$ is a dense subset of $\tilde{X}$ and $\rho(u,v)=\tilde{\rho}(u,v)$ for any $u,v\in X$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch:

The idea is as follows: Suppose $Y$ and $Z$ are completions of $X$. If $y\in Y$, there is some sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in $X$ with $x_n\to y$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy in $X$; it is Cauchy in $Z$, so it converges to some point. Now shows tthat, if $\{x_n'\}$ is another sequence in $X$ converging to $y$ in $Y$, $\{x_n'\}$ converges to the same point in $Z$ as  $\{x_n\}$.

This allows us to define a function $f:Y\to Z$ by
$$
f(y):=\lim_{n\to\infty}^Z x_n
$$
where $\{x_n\}$ is any sequence in $X$ converging to $y\in Y$.

The next step is to show that $f$ is isometric.

By symmetry, you have an analogous isometry $g:Z\to Y$ going in the opposite direction. Then $f\circ g$ is the identity when restricted to $X$ (can you see why?), and so it is the identity on all of $Z$ by density. By the same reasoning, $g\circ f = id_Y$.

EDIT: I misspoke before, it's actually easier to show directly that $f$ is isometric.

Fix $y,y'\in Y$. Fix sequences $\{x_n\},\{x_n'\}$ in $X$ which converge to $y$ and $y'$, respecticely. Then
$$
d_Z(f(y),f(y'))= \lim_n d_Z(x_n,x_n')=\lim_n d_Y(x_n,x_n')=d_Y(y,y')
$$
Thus $f$ is isometric, hence continuous.

If $x\in X$, then $(x,x,\dots)$ is a sequence in $Y$ which converges to $x$. So $f(x)$ is the limit in $Z$ of that constant sequence, which is just $x$. So, $f(x)=x$.

Comment: I have two questions: First, how to show $f$ is continuous? Second, I don't quite understand f composite g is the identity restricted to $X$. Can you add more details?

Comment: @PseudodifferentialOperators See my edit